# Script to get a list of local IPs and look for an IP

Tags: shell-script, ip

I would like a script to look for an IP address among others.

I use the following command to generate the list:

```
ip -4 neighbor show
```

But I don't know how to look.

```
command | awk ...
```

or

```
for i in command ; do ... done
```

Finally this seems to be correct:

```
LIST=$(the regex of Reda Salih)  
for i in $LIST
do
  if [ "${i}" == $my_ip]
  then
    echo found
    exit 0
  fi
done
echo not found
```

But is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: It would be easier if you show us the output of the command and an example of the desired output of the script. Please edit your question.

Comment: The command "ip -4 neighbor show" provides a list of IP. My desired output is True or false according to the presence or not of a specific IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grep with following regex :

```
ip -4 neighbor show | grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" | grep -oh <ip_addr>
```

Just replace <ip_addr> with your IP..

Comment: Ok but how to find a specific IP is present  in this list ?

Comment: I have updated the post. Don't forgot to make it as resolved / answered. Thanks

Comment: if <ip_addr> is 192.168.1.1 your solution find 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.10

Comment: I have added '-oh' flags to the last grep, so it will show only the matched word. It will be fine now !

Comment: OK Thank you for your solution